# Google maps on mobile with gestureHandling = cooperative still fires click event

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When on a mobile device, if I want to scroll the page by clicking somewhere on the Google map and scrolling down, I still receive a click event.

I see the "use two fingers to move the map" message, and the page is scrolling as expected but I receive a click event after. And I use this click event to add a marker. So at this point, it's messing the behavior of the whole page.

Here is a simple jsfiddle to reproduce (on mobile of course, or in mobile mode on chrome https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/):

Just scroll down while clicking on the map and an alert with the text "Click Event" will popup.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (evt) { 
    alert("Click Event");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/83o1my1p/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to use a var and change it state on touch events. Then use it in the click event:

```
var dragged = false;

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (evt) {
    if (!dragged) {
        // Do stuff here
    }
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(canvas, 'touchmove', function (event) {
    if (event.touches.length == 1) {
        dragged = true;
    }
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(canvas, 'touchend', function(event) {
    dragged = false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this problem has already been reported in Google issue tracker. Have a look at the following bug:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64586414

Feel free to add a star in the bug to express your interest and subscribe to notifications. Also, note that the person who filed the bug also found a workaround:

> The clicks can be prevent after the scroll, the same way they they are prevented after dragend events when using on a desktop.  As I said above, I worked around it myself by handling the mousedown event, and comparing the location of it, to the location of the click event.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the link, I starred it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the work around I used.

```
var mouseDownPos = null;

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function(e) { mouseDownPos = e.pixel });
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    var mouseUpPos = e.pixel;
    var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseDownPos.x - mouseUpPos.x, 2) + Math.pow(mouseDownPos.y - mouseUpPos.y, 2));
    if(distance > 10) return; // Adjust for tolerance

    // Do what you need here
});
```